# Underlying geometry of integrals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, integration

When mathematicians refer to the "underlying geometry" of an integral (integral as in the integral calculus), what exactly does this mean? And, given a specific integral, how do you know what the underlying geometry is? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: So... perhaps cite an example where a mathematician wrote the "underlying geometry" of an integral.

Comment: @CEdgar I was looking at this on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30659/establishing-zeta3-as-a-definite-integral-and-its-computation (see the accepted answer)

Comment: As in: "period integrals are manifestations of underlying geometry" ... Most "integrals" that you see in the integral calulus are not "period integrals".

Comment: So in the case of the link provided, "period integrals" are those related to geometry of a circular nature. Ok. Hmm, that now makes me wonder why the $\zeta$ values are linked to circular geometry at all. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could mean many things, for example the fact that $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is "really" the length of a semicircle, and can therefore be evaluated to $\pi$ without any calculations. I don't think you can know in advance what the "underlying geometry" is; but following sufficiently many SE questions will give you a feeling for it. Another rich source of examples is the Cauchy residue theorem which allows you to evaluate numerous intergals via geometric considerations.